# About memory management in iPhone

Tags: iphone, memory-management

Please clarify the following thing.

Everyone knows that; if we are using `alloc`, `retain`, `new` and `etc...`, we have to release it. For remaining things, we have to use `autorelease`. My doubt is;

```
-(NSArray*)getArray{
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", nil];
    return [array autorelease];
}
```

```
NSArray *arr = [self getArray];
---
---
```

What we have to do the `arr`?

**EDIT:**

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome..."];
```

If we are using the above statement, we should call `autorelease`. But I want to know, what is happening in the `stringWithFormat:`method. How it is returning `NSString`.

Thanks.

Comment: It's actually really import to show us the rest of the code where arr would be used. If it's all in the same method where you call getArray, then you don't have to do anything at all.

Comment: As a side note, according to the naming conventions the prefix "get" is used only for methods that return objects indirectly.

Comment: I added an answer to your question about [NSString stringWithFormat:] below.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to return the array, go ahead and use the [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", etc, nil] instead.

You then just need to remember to retain it if you want to hold on to it for longer then the autorelease pool will hold it.

The autorelease pool will give it a retain count of 1, and then automatically decrement it by 1 when the release pool gets called. Without retaining it in the calling function, this object will eventually disappear.

Comment: What is happening in arrayWithObjects: method ? the same thing I asked for stringWithFormat:. Already when return the object, they have used autorelease, then again why we need to use autorelease ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything with arr since you didn't explicitly `alloc`, `copy`, `new`, or `retain` it in its current scope. It's already been added to the autorelease pool so it'll automatically be cleaned up once you're done with it.

**EDIT**: In your edited question, `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` returns an autoreleased string. It's basically doing the same thing as you're doing in your getArray method. It builds a NSString (or related) object and autoreleases it before it's returned.

Comment: If it is returning an autoreleased string means, again we no need to use autoreleased. right ? Why people are saying like we should use autorelease method for the returned string ? Please clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

You should retain:

```
[[self getArray] retain];
```

Or return non-autoreleased object in `getArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Your getArray method is returning an NSArray that _will_be_ released when the stack fully unwinds.

In the method where you are calling your getArray method, it is safe to use the NSArray, but if you want to keep it, and use it after your current method returns, you will need to retain the NSArray with [arr retain].

**Answer to your new question**

Class methods, like [NSString stringWithFormat:] or like [NSURL URLWithString:] return objects that have been autoreleased. This is a convention, a standard practice in UIKit and the Apple frameworks.

Comment: Correct. If you get an object from [NSString stringWithFormat:] you don't need to release it.